# Red ink for Windows 8 Reader App

Tags: windows-8, tablet, pdf-reader

I'm using the Windows 8 Reader app on a Surface Pro, and I really like the feature that enables you to mark up a PDF with the stylus. Is there any way to change the color of the digital "ink" created when the stylus touches the screen (say, red instead of the default black)?